# Python Loop Numbers Various Ways

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to get python 3.4 to loop a sequence of numbers like this:

```
0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
```

What's the easiest way to do this?

Also need a separate one to loop them this way:

```
0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2
```

This is the coding I have so far but it's not doing that quite like I want it:

```
for i in range (10):
    for j in range(1)
        for k in range(1)
            print(j,end=' ')
        prin('\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do as follows:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(" ".join(map(str, range(0,i+1))))


0
0 1
0 1 2
0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4
0 1 2 3 4 5
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9


for i in range(10):
    print("{} ".format(i)*10)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 
3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 
6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 
7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 
8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 
9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without using the range function, but rather, doing a nested loop?

Comment: Sorry, not what I meant... I mean, is there a way to do this doing a loop inside of a loop instead of using the ".join(map(str"? Something more basic like:

Comment: for i in range (10) followed by for j in range... etc

Answer (score 0):

[repeat](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)

```
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> for num in range(3):
...    print(list(repeat(num, 5)))
... 
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

and

```
>>> for i in range(1, 4):
...    print(list(range(i)))
...
[0]
[0, 1]
[0, 1, 2]
```